# How to call a xml web service in asp.net mvc 4.0 and 5.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have to integrate UPS location api with my asp.net mvc 4.0 based application. The location api support only XML standards please guide me to achieve the following tasks:
1- Call XML web-service from MVC view.
2- Call XML web-service from MVC Controller.

Comment: Reference the web service in your application, call the webservice in your controller, serialize the result of webservice as XML and return from Action as a ContentResult.

Comment: Thanks @fabiosilvalima it solves my problem.